# Postgres "Materialized View" refresh as source of ElasticSearch document updates?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, materialized-views

I have a normalized database with several tables in a AWS RDS Postgres database, with about a million records.

I'd like to write a Materialized View that joins several of these tables to produce a record structure for ElasticSearch documents.

When the Materialized View is refreshed (I'll use the concurrent option), I'd like to the activity to be pushed to AWS ElasticSearch as inserts or updates or deletes accordingly.

I would only modify the underlying tables and refresh the materialized view once per week.

Would this work - specifically do refreshes of materialized views get logged as insert/update/deletes in the WAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this at a project I am working on and so far it's working fine, I use logstash as a standalone app and each time I want to update the data, I refresh the materialized view and run logstash using the postgres driver (in my case I have a job on the server that do that each 2 hours).
To do that, you'll need to run the command line:
    `path/to/logstash/bin/logstash -f path/to/postgres2elasticsearch.conf`

And on file "postgres2elasticsearch.conf" you should put:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}"
        jdbc_user => "${RDS_USERNAME}"
        jdbc_password => "${RDS_PASSWORD}"
        jdbc_driver_library => "${DRIVE_PATH}"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from ${MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW} order by ${ID_FIELD}"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "${ES_INDEX}"
        hosts => ["${ES_DATA_HOST}:443"]
    }
}
```

The `order by` clause on the query is important because logstash will insert the data in batches and if you don't order the data, it's possible that a part of the data comes duplicated and other part doesn't come to elasticsearch at all, so I suggest you have an indexed unique field on you materialized view for that matter. And you will need to download the [postgres jdbc driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and put it on ${DRIVE_PATH}

Comment: Does logstash re index complete table again or is somehow able to detect inserts/updates/delete. If it's reindexing again how well it scales ? Maybe like 50M records in matview.